# Redux-Form reset field with custom component

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm very new to react, redux and redux-form (and frontend in general :D).
I have a component with a form and a `Field` with a custom component.

```
const SomeComponent = ({ .. }) => (
<div>
...
<Field
    name="someName"
    component="select"
    ...
/>
<Field
    name="someName"
    component={CustomComponent}
    ...
/>
</div>
)
```

When I create this component:

```
<SomeComponent
    form={form}
    onSubmitSuccess={(data, dispatch) => dispatch(reset(form))} />
```

The first field is cleared correctly but the second it's not. What do I have to do to make my `CustomComponent` aware of the reset?

Comment: Your component is `connected` to the store, so , once you dispatch an action, that action changes the store, and your component re-renders according to new data. But your `CustomComponent` is probably not connected, so it doesn't know data changed.

Comment: please add your implementation of `CustomComponent `

Comment: @JoãoVilaça way simpler than I thought! :-)

Comment: how come? @Raffaeu

Comment: Just play with props.value and props.change(value) and you are fully in sync with the parent store